# Issue in authenticating user with valid google analytics account

Tags: omniauth

I'm using omniauth-google-oauth2 for authenticating to google and google app accounts.In my app, users login with their google accounts to view their google analytics data.
Authenticaton is done properly when user logins correctly with a valid GA account but gives me error when the account is not registered with Google analytics as

```
{
    "errors" = > [{
        "domain" = > "global", "reason" = > "insufficientPermissions", "message" = > "User does not have any Google Analytics account."
    }], "code" = > 403, "message" = > "User does not have any Google Analytics account."
}:
```

Don't know how to handle this and redirect users back to the login page by giving an error message that "Account is not registered with GA"

Answer (score 0):

What's your omniauth scope? My guess is that you have something in your scope.

If you change your setting to the following default in your omniauth.rb (or whatever initializer file you are using):

```
provider :google_oauth2, "yourappid", "yourkey"
```

Then the problem is likely to go away. If so, then what happens here is that you did not ask for enough permission. By default, the scope="userinfo.email,userinfo.profile". If you want an additional permission, for example, "somepermission". Then instead of using the following

```
provider :google_oauth2, "yourappid", "yourkey", :scope => "somepermission"
```

You should use

```
provider :google_oauth2, "yourappid", "yourkey", :scope => "userinfo.email,userinfo.profile,somepermission"
```

Otherwise it won't give you the email/profile necessary for omniauth to work.